# Destructor not called

Tags: c++, destructor, c++builder-xe2

This is excerpt from my WinMain method. It is not complete but I think it is sufficient to illustrate core of problem. Please don't ask why I am deleting data module explicitly when it should be done automatically. This is entirely another issue (has to do with incorrect finalization order when application initialization ends prematurely with exception in one of constructors).

```
extern PACKAGE TDataModule_Local *DataModule_Local;

class TDataModule_Local :
   public TDataModule
{
...
public:
   __fastcall        TDataModule_Local(TComponent *Owner);
   __fastcall        ~TDataModule_Local();
}

WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int)
{
    Application->Initialize();
    Application->CreateForm(__classid(TMainForm), &MainForm);
    Application->CreateForm(__classid(TDataModule_Local), &DataModule_Local);    
    Application->Run();    

    if (DataModule_Local != NULL)
    {
       delete DataModule_Local;     // destructor not called! why?
       DataModule_Local = NULL;
    }

    return 0;    
}
```

Whats weird destructor of data module is not called when I use delete operator. Is is called after program reaches enclosing brace of WinMain method:

[image]

Comment: Is this your real code? Does the base class have a virtual destructor?

Comment: Yes TDataModule (a Delphi class) has virtual destructor. But I think its irrelevant because we declared pointer to derived class.

Comment: That shouldn't matter as it's not being deleted through a pointer to the base class.

Comment: How have you determined that the destructor isn't (also) called when you call `delete`?

Comment: @Agentlien: Program execution doesn't stop on breakpoint as seen on screenshot.

Comment: Maybe CreateForm assigns 0 to DataModule_Local so your delete is never called because of the "if" ?

Comment: @Zar Shardan: That's not the case. I have debbugged application line by line. I even created empty application from scratch with same behaviour.

Comment: Why is the destructor not called? Probably because DataModule_Local doesn't contain a pointer returned by a new statement.

Answer (score 1):

You said

> deleting data module explicitly when it should be done automatically

Obviously whatever code is designed to free it automatically is still trying to do so, blissfully ignorant of your problems with finalization order.

Just because you've set your pointer to NULL doesn't mean that there isn't a copy of the pointer sitting in a list of objects to be cleaned up on exit.